# Difficult Definite Integral with ArcCosh

Tags: calculus

How can I solve this integral containing inverse cosh? Does it have any antiderivative?

$$\int_b^r\ t^2 \frac {\cosh^{-1} ({\frac {a} {t}})} {\sqrt {r^2 - t^2}}\ dt$$

with the assumptions  $0<b<r<a$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you have tried? Reagrds

Comment: can you please check that on the denominator if its r or a you will get answer easily if both numerator and denominator have either a or r with substitution t= a sechu and simplify and then use separate in to 2 integrals and first one use by parts second one use inverse chain rule.

Comment: The assumptions are that strictly b < r < a  (all three different)

Comment: The assumption is that b<r<a strictly (all three are different)

Comment: I was able to solve the integral (i.e. the antiderivative) with t instead of t^2 as the first factor in the integrand.